# Inequality constrained least squares with python using 'COBYLA' algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

My goal is to minimize least squares (i.e. "fit" the function) with respect, that the returned function is non-decreasing, which means that the derivative in all points on I is >=0.

My function of choice is 4th degree polynomial function, i.e,

```
f(x) = a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x + e
```

For this task, its best to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` method. I built very robust iteration algorithm, that search the points where my the result fuction from 'minimize' is decreasing, and sets the inequality constraint. For example, if in point x0 is f(x) decreasing, my constraint is:

```
4*a*x0**3 + 3*b*x0**2 + 2*c*x0 + d >= 0
```

For some of my data I succedet using 'SLSQP' optimization method WITH the inequality constraint as is described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#tutorial-sqlsp). Its odd because the of minimize [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) of minimize states, that:

"Note that COBYLA only supports inequality constraints."

So my first question: 1] Is the tutorial from first link mistaken?

Even if it is right, it looks that I cant use 'SLSQP' for another datam because of 'incompatible constraints' issue from minimize process.

Now for the 'COBYLA algorithm' I want to use, because there could be some points, where f(x) is decreasing. Here is the sample code:

```
#STACK
#[  1.01766416e-04,   1.80575564e-06,  -7.51840485e-03, -7.51828086e-03,   9.84985357e-01]


import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def ecdf(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    F = [len(arr[arr<=t]) / len(arr) for t in arr]
    return np.array(F)

def der(args_pol, point):
    a, b, c, d, e = args_pol
    return (4*a*point**3 + 3*b*point**2 + 2*c*point + d)

def least_sq(args_pol, x, y):
    a, b, c, d, e = args_pol
    return ((y-(a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x + e))**2).sum()  


var = np.array([ 6.8,  6.9,  7. ,  7.4,  7.4,  7.5,  7.5,  7.6,  7.7,  7.8,  8. ,
                8. ,  8. ])

ec = ecdf(var)
tip = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
const = []

opt = minimize(least_sq, tip, method = 'COBYLA', args = (var, ec),
               constraints = const)
```

The result from optimization proces is my second coment. The result function, if you plot it looks like this.

[image]

As you can see, the result function fits my data VERY poorly, even withouth any constraints. I saw similar behaviour for for data, where I needed some constraints as well, sometimes the result function event worse than this example. So my second question is:

2] Can anybody explain me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: COBYLA only supports ineqs, SLSQP eqs and ineqs. What's unclear? *"Note that COBYLA only supports inequality constraints."* never says it's the only alg to be able to do that.

Comment: thank you for explanation, I am not native english speaker, so I translatet that poorly. Could you answer my second question as well?

Comment: For this (1) you should make your code complete (const is missing) (2) making clear what you want: why mentioning SLSQP error without showing code when then asking about COBYLA (3) explain what you mean by *even without any constraints* while having constraints=const in the code.

Comment: (1) and (3) there is const = [] mentioned. (2) I asked because I misunderstood the tutorial, as I wrote in previos comment.

Comment: Ok, i did not see that. Well... try other solvers for the unconstrained case and observe what's happening. And more important (for all solvers): check different random initial-points and observe the results (probably not by plot: too slow; more within a loop and looking at function-objective)

Comment: Yep I did that. For 'SLSQP' the fit is very nice, but for constrained problems I often got an error about incopatible constraints. I found out, that this issue can occur for some initial points a for another it doesnt so I do use 241 different initial points (combinations of 1 and 0 in array of length 5), but sometimes it does not work for any of them. Do you thing that I could use negative initial points as well?

Comment: If there is some error, show code which produces that error which we can run. It sounds you did build some outer global-opt layer without showing any of it. I think there are some checks on constraints before running the optimizer. So it seems your constraints do make the problem infeasible.